# variable count not increasing inside for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, xlsxwriter

```
for keys in dict:
        count=0
        outSheet.write(2, count+1, keys)
        print(count)
        count = count +1
```

I want to copy the keys of the dictionary **dict** into a excel sheet.
I expected outSheet.write function to copy the keys into the excel file starting at coordinate (count+1 ,2) and increase the y coordinate by 1 per iteration. But the value of count doesnt seem to increase per iteration.
what should I do to increase the value of count so that all the keys could be copied.
thank you

Comment: i have updated your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in the loop is setting count to 0 doesn’t matter how many time’s you loop it will always be reset back to 0. Remove that to outside the loop if you want to increment

```
count=0
```

Also change your increment to this it’s cleaner

```
count += 1
```

Like this

```
count = 0
for keys in dict:
    outSheet.write(2, count+1, keys)
    print(count)
    count += 1
```